# Start Django config app only once when using multiple Gunicorn workers

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, gunicorn

I'm using :

- python 3.6
- django==2.1.1
- gunicorn==19.9.0

i have done the following:

- created a django project called `api`
- created an `apiapp` (an app in my project)

and i have this code in api_app's `apps.py` :

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from api import settings

class ApiappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apiapp'
    verbose_name = "random_name"

    def ready(self):
        self.job()


    @classmethod
    def job(cls):
        ### doing whatever here for example :
        print(settings.SHARED_VARIABLE)
```

and the following in api_app's `__init__.py`:

```
import os
default_app_config = 'apiapp.apps.ApiappConfig'
```

i'm creating an API so i am required to use multiple workers when deploying:

```
gunicorn api.wsgi -w 10
```

now, my issue is that the function `job` which is called when the server is started, is getting called 10 times because i'm using 10 gunicorn workers, i would like to call it only once

another thing that i would like to do is to have the 
`settings.SHARED_VARIABLE` variable, shared between the different workers. this variable will be updated only by the worker that will launch the `app.py` on server start.

Thank you !

Comment: This wouldn't make sense. Data is not shared between processes. If you only invoked it once, it would only be available to that single worker.

Comment: @DanielRoseman oki, i'll worry about the data sharing later, what about the apps.py issue ?

Comment: not only apps.py, but settings.py will be called ten times if you have multiple works.How about use multi thread mode:`gunicorn api.wsgi -k gthread -w 1 --threads 8`

Comment: Gunicorn workers are for servicing APIs. 
In general, I see an issue with the whole architecture: your job should be an external Django command (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/). 
How it is started is completely different topic but it is far easier to start two different processes than trying to cope with gunicorn agents.
You could also use the `on_starting` guncorn function and invoke the above mentioned custom admin command.

Comment: @fcracker79 i don't understand what you're recommending me to do

Comment: I recommend to implement a custom admin command and invoke it in the `on_starting` configuration entry for gunicorn.

Comment: Roseman is right. Why don't you put the shared variable in the database? Since you need it to be consistency?

Comment: @Sarit that's a good idea i'll try it .... oki so let's say that this is the solution to the shared variable problem, what about the apps.py running multiple time problem ? that's the most important thing here

Comment: When I need to dispatch for a `job` in the background I normally work with `Celery + RabbitMQ` or `Redis`. You might need to consider that way.

Comment: @Sarit i'm already using redis as a channels layer for django channels ... how do you recommend that i use it for this issue ? i'm don't have experience with celery, redis .. etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gunicorn has a setting to do this: [`--preload`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#preload-app)

So, after I add this in `settings.py`: `SHARED_VARIABLE = 'content of SHARED_VARIABLE'` (and fixed `apiapp/__init__.py` to use the real app name), I can run gunicorn with the application loaded only once:

```
$ gunicorn api.wsgi -w 10 --preload
content of SHARED_VARIABLE
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [394] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [394] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (394)
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [394] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [399] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 399
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [400] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 400
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [401] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 401
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [403] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 403
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [404] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 404
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [405] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 405
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [406] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 406
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [408] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 408
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [410] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 410
[2018-12-31 10:12:15 +0000] [411] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 411
```

Comment: i will have to save the shared variable in a file or db for it to be changed in the workers everytime it is changed in the thread created by the preload ? (i will create a thread in preload that does scheduled task that will update the content of the shared variable, i'm using threading and schedule modules)

Comment: Either that or use one of the tools provided by `multiprocessing` to communicate between processes. eg https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects

Comment: but then how would i send those objects to the workers ?

Comment: just create the proxies before forking